# AWS lambda parameters is empty in golang

Tags: amazon-web-services, go, aws-lambda

I have a small program in Golang:

```
package main

    import (
        "github.com/aws/aws-lambda-go/lambda"
        "log"
    )

    type Request struct {
        //{"message": "Hey, are you there?" }
        Message string `json:"message"`
    }

    func ToUpperHandler(r Request) {
        log.Println("["+r.Message+"]")
    }

    func main() {
        lambda.Start(ToUpperHandler)
    }
```

This is AWS lambda handler. I would like to test it localy:

```
echo '{"message": "Hey, are you there?" }' | sam local invoke "Resize"
```

and it logs just "[]" so r.Message is empty. 
Here is my template.yaml:

```
AWSTemplateFormatVersion : '2010-09-09'
Transform: AWS::Serverless-2016-10-31
Resources:
  Resize:
    Type: AWS::Serverless::Function
    Properties:
      Handler: resize
      Runtime: go1.x
```

Am i missing something? Because almost the same code works if it is deployed on amazon.

Comment: your handler name is `ToUpperHandler` right but you use `resize` in yaml?

Comment: Yes, compiled binary named as resize so it's correct, I think

Comment: try to  build yaml file using `sam build`